# w3 total cache cache folder

Tags: wordpress, caching, plugins, ftp

W3 total cache plugin generated a folder named cache. This folder is inside my wp-content. Im trying to delete this, i actually tried to delete the folder now this is happening:

[image]

40000 files.. its been doing this for like 2 hours i think maybe more. this isnt normal at all. why is this and how can i speed up the process.

Comment: If you have cpanel access with your host, find the file and delete it there, or use ftp to delete the file. I am assuming you have uninstalled W3 cache and no longer want to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up deleting this file after 2 hours. 50 000 files were in there which were not being used. Did it through the cpanel of my host.